# Concatenating strings with mathematical symbols in Python 3

Tags: python, string, dictionary, concatenation

I created a dictionary for peoples' names as such:

```
names = {"first": , "second": , "third":}
```

What I want to do is call each name and combine them as a string, being separated by a plus sign. Below is a tedious way of doing it:

```
str(names["first"]) + "+" + str(names["second"]) + "+" + str(names["third"])
```

This line is from a larger module I am attempting to create. I tried to following for simplicity, but it resulted in a syntax error:

```
str(names["first"] "%+d" + names["second"] "%+d" + names["third"])
```

Is there a way of simplifying the above so that it prints:

> firstname+secondname+thirdname

Comment: your dictionary `names` contains only keys, but no values.

Comment: As @bouvierr said, your dictionary has no values. In your OP when you say: `"firstname+secondname+thirdname"` do you actually want `name` to be the names that are the values in the dictionary, if your dictionary actually had values?

Comment: No, sorry I neglected to put the names in. I actually do have them in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 2 you have to use the slightly hacky

```
"{first}+{second}+{third}".format(**names)
```

However, as GingerPlusPlus points out, in python 3 you can get away from this `**kwargs` chicanery and instead use [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map)

```
"{first}+{second}+{third}".format_map(names)
```

Comment: Damnit i really should forget all the hacks I had to use when writing python 2 code.

Comment: Thanks alot guys. Really appereciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `namedtuple` instead of `dict` to store names, I'd suggest:

```
'+'.join(map(str, names))
```